# Reference for a multiple composite hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, composite

I am finding out a good reference or paper for a multiple composite hypotheses.

(e.g. $H_0: \theta_j \geq 0\;\forall\;j=1,\ldots,\;J$)

Is there any material you recommend?

Comment: Lehmacher et al Biometrics. Something about composite endpoints, around 1990.

Comment: O’Brien PC. Procedures for Comparing Samples with Multiple Endpoints. Biometrics 1984; 40(4): 1079 - 1087